# sqlite3_step gives an error

Tags: ios4, sqlite, ios5.1

I have a project created in iOS 4. But I have to move to iOS 5.1. When I run it in iOS 5.1, it gives an error in here.

`

```
 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

        NSLog(@"2nd if");

        while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){

            NSLog(@"error: %s\n",sqlite3_errmsg(database));`
```

This error message is print as unknown error
But there is a simmilar code to load a UITableView. It works without any issue. This has run on iOS 4 without any issue. Can any one help me

Thanks

Comment: without posting your sql-statement this is nearly impossible to analyse. that may be an file or security issue as well.